# Count child elements of "this"

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure and want to count number of `input` within outer `foo` - there might be several instances of `foo` on one page, therefore I want to count within each instance

```
<div class="foo">
  <div>
    <input type="text...>
    <label></label>
    <input type="text...>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm trying, but of course it fails because `this` is an abject and `div` and `input` are not

```
$(".foo").each( function () {
  console.log( $(this > div > input).length );
})
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `$(this).find("input").length`

Comment: `console.log(this.getElementsByTagName('input').length);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".foo").each( function () {
  console.log( $(this).find('> div > input').length );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/n80ju0uy/)

```
$(".foo").each( function () {
  console.log( $(this).find('input').length );
})
```